# Is it possible to tell typescript a variable cannot be undefined via throwing an exception?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Look at the Class B ready() function in the code below. Typescript says, someVar is possibly undefined. Fact is it's not due to the thrown error by the parent method. Is it possible to tell typescript to check such thing? I do not want to use the exclamation mark if possible. Maybe there is some tsconfig property I obviously don't know?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0AOAnA9gFwFNhCATaCHAWwIDUwsAuaAOwFdKAjAraAH2lbMSBAGYBLZgRIBuVKnTAczCHiytiOLAAoK1OoxbsuPfoOHjJJAJSJ56aHgAWYiADpdtetAC85Kp6xZNGgAXzlg7HwiUmgsAjASAE8tKwYANxwxMmRg9DERaC0nF3d-fR9vXzNRCSkbJ1wAd2gAUSxcbQByD3LqiylOqyD7aEVlHBACVxAcAHMtToBJOABZaAAlFtgAEQBNAEJDweHQ8PQMVg4QMWBoWYI8Pz16AHkRWBSmNk5uPgEhGqWWy5WIPVhYZgOZxuHr0E5hFAI1CgSAwABC0AIAA9CEIYPAcnYxio1BptLCsAB+L5GbhWHIjCCsDDcHRlehDOzoYpuOIJZKc4JIiK4QjEKSg-mfDJZYGM5ncVx8pIpE4KJQUSbTOYLZYkHAsfCjfwAGmg+SeAX+5lqZEc3AIxy50AA1C6eaVnoE7AjhSioNAAMJyzBYMRpMCEaAcJhooJEjWqdR4TQpBn2D0cHwsAjNNGq53EiZTGbzTOegJvWCC9C+8KSZqB1VAA)

```
class A {
  protected someVar: number | undefined;

  constructor(someVar: number | undefined) {
    this.someVar = someVar;
  }

  protected ready():void {
    if (this.someVar === undefined) throw Error('someVar undefined');
    console.log('I AM READY!!!');
  }

  public get someVarOfA(): number | undefined {
    return this.someVar;
  }
}

class B extends A {

  constructor(someVar?: number){
    super(someVar);
    this.ready();
  }

  protected ready():void {
    super.ready();
    console.log('I do not come here, if someVar undefined');
    ++this.someVar;
  }
}

class C {
  private b: B;

  constructor(){
    this.b = new B();
    console.log(this.b.someVarOfA);
  }
}

new C();
```

#### EDIT

This is my current use case scenario:
I have many scenes which all extend SuperScene. SuperScene has no constructor and cannot have without redesigning 75% of the (bad)code.

```
class SceneA extends SuperScene {
  public ready(): void {
    // throws error if sceneB === undefined
    super.ready();
    
    // typescript complains: sceneB could be undefined
    this.sceneB.doSomething();

    // this is async
    this.doA(() => {
      // typescript complains: sceneB could be undefined
      this.sceneB.whatever = 1
    });
    this.doB(() => {
      // typescript complains: sceneB could be undefined
      this.sceneB.whatever = 2
    });
    this.doC(() => {
      // typescript complains: sceneB could be undefined
      this.sceneB.whatever = 3
    });
    // few more of these ...

    // sceneAssets is a class as well as images, videos and documents
    // ts complains: sceneB, images,videos, documents could be undefined
    this.sceneB.sceneAssets.doSomething();
    this.sceneB.sceneAssets.images.doSomething();
    this.sceneB.sceneAssets.videos.doSomething();
    this.sceneB.sceneAssets.documents.doSomething();
    // more sceneC, sceneD ...
    
    // there would be no scene if images, videos or documents would be
    // undefined but all scenes have no constructor. Currently they cannot
    // have one because they all get created at a time, where all the needed
    // data is not available. => In theory, every class member could be
    // undefined. But not inside ready().
  }
}
```

Currently I have this as a "solution":

```
// at the beginning before calling super.ready();
if (!this.sceneB?.sceneAssets?.images || !this.sceneB?.sceneAssets?.videos || !this.sceneB?.sceneAssets?.documents) throw Error('...');

// Inside every async
if (!this.sceneB) throw Error('...');
```

Comment: I doubt you can use the code like that without using the assertion operation. What is your actual use case? I'd probably redesign the whole class, to only create an instance once it's actually ready.

Comment: Maybe if you annotate `ready`’s return type as an assertion predicate (of the form `asserts this is this & {someVar: number` and the `protected` modifier probably complicates things) but I can’t test that until I get off mobile.

Comment: @jcalz I thought about that, but you'd still have to change the code to `if (super.ready()) { …; ++this.someVar; }`, no?

Comment: Not with an `asserts` predicate, if it works that is.

Comment: @jcalz Oh, [I didn't know about those](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), I though you meant a type predicate

Comment: @jcalz Looks like such assertion works only if assertion method is defined in the same class but not in parent

Comment: @Bergi that is what I am facing actually but I have to delay that to the next year. We have a deadline. :/

Comment: @jcalz I have the same problem with other functions which have a return type declared. But I'll look into asserts.

Comment: @Bergi yes, it looks like `super.ready()` doesn't do anything to `this` for some reason.  

Comment: @aProgger It doesn't look promising.  You can do `asserts this is...` but it doesn't get triggered on `super` for some reason.  I might make a feature request to support it but it wouldn't be in the language anytime soon even if it isn't closed as declined.

Comment: "*this is async: `this.doA(() => { this.sceneB.whatever = 1; /* typescript complains: sceneB could be undefined */ })`*" - I think in that case, TypeScript will keep complaining. If you do a type assertion for a variable or property, then use it in a callback function, the type assertion won't cover that since the variable or property might have changed in the meantime.

Comment: You could however do `const { sceneB } = this; if (!sceneB) throw …;` at the start of the function, and then just use `sceneB` throughout, if you don't expect the property to change anyway

Comment: I made a epic in our scrum to add a constructor to the class. One developer already yelled at me and another "run" away ^^ Thank you for your help and time guys